# PHP file operation - how to disable file size always showing while reading a file?

Tags: php, html

My question is how do I disable / remove the file size displayed at the top of the output whenever I read a file and output its content. I have given the code below with a pic

This is the code:

```
<?php

$data1 = "
<html>
    <body>
        <div style='width:400; height:400px; background-color: #333;'>
        <h1>This is Somnath</h1>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
";

echo file_put_contents("test2.html", $data1);

echo readfile("test2.html");

/*
include ("test2.html");


$filename = "test2.html";
$file = fopen($filename,"r");
$filesize = filesize($filename);
$fileread =  fread($file, $filesize);
echo ($fileread);


*/


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
echo file_put_contents("test2.html", $data1);
echo readfile("test2.html");
```

With:

```
file_put_contents("test2.html", $data1);
readfile("test2.html");
```

---

According to the [`readfile()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) documentation, this function:

> reads a file and writes it to the output buffer.

This mean it automatically goes to the output buffer and you don't need to `echo` the return value. In fact, the return value is:

> the number of bytes read from the file.

---

This is the same for [`file_put_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php), since it returns:

> the number of bytes that were written to the file.

Comment: Sorry Sam...  did it but same result

Comment: Uploaded 2 images to show the problem details. Please have a look. Is there any way to change the configuration file to disable this? Case1: http://i.share.pho.to/92216e16_o.png  Case2: http://i.share.pho.to/d80d7146_o.png Thanks in Advance

Comment: Did you remove the `echo` from both functions?

Comment: Glad it worked. Please accept my answer so that others can quickly find what they are looking for if they stumble across the same issue.